# Duplicate v4 Support issue.Tried all options.Help Needed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-2.0, android-gradle-2.2

I am working nearly 2 days to get rid of v4 **dulicate issue** on signed `apk` build.I have Two Modules. The one `SDK` which connects FB has v4 SUpport.

I have excluded v4 from everywhere on `gradle` but still i am getting

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.class

**Gradle:app  :**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.madlab.wapp.sais"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 4
        versionName "2.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1')
        compile project(':getsocialize')
    }
}

**Gradle: sdk:**

    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'


dependencies {
    compile 'com.socialize:facebook:3.1.3-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.socialize:ioc:3.1.3-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.socialize:loopy:3.1.7'
    // compile 'com.socialize:library:3.1.6'
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testApplicationId "com.socialize.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.socialize.SocializeTestRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        androidTest.setRoot('../test')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

I could see the class is in both v7 and v4 with CNtl+N even after exclude on v7.

[**image description**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSqzN.png)

even if i manually remove the jar Whenever i ran build i am getting jar automatically in 
`C:\Users\subash\AndroidStudioProjects\Sais\sdk\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.socialize\facebook\3.1.3-SNAPSHOT\jars\libs.`

I ran dependencies on gradle also No issue identified on that.  I really appreciate help and guidance for solving the issue

Adding External Libraries V4 issue:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLsS9.png)

Comment: CNTL+N result in android studio for 
DrawableCompat.class is in (support-compat.25.3.1)(classes.jar)  and also in facebook-3.1.3-SNAPSHOT (android-support-v4.jar) . I tried to get rid of anyone of the jar.but couldn't succeed.

Comment: What is in your "libs"?

Comment: @jared Burrows i have added more details

Comment: If you remove the app-compat dependency does it work? AppCompat also brings in v4.

Comment: Thanks @JaredBurrows. I have changed app compact theme to material and dependency resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed app compactV7(used for app theme) which includes v4-support on compile and changed app theme to material  .

Comment: Yeah but this is not ideal as material is min api 21. Unless you want to start with a minsdk of 21.

Comment: Yes. I couldn't fine any choice. As this app is for small group of audience i felt that would be fine